# What is the purpose of 0-length midi notes?

Tags: software, midi

I have several midi files that contain notes with 0 duration. There will be a note_on event, then the next event for the same note says note_off and the time attribute is 0. Is there a purpose to these 0-length midi notes?

Comment: Do you know what sound these notes are intended to trigger?

Comment: One could suspect a lame editing software, which instead of delete a note, just put its length to zero…

Comment: @Tom_C That was my thought! I just wan't sure if somehow a 0-length note would get played for some microsecond, like a grace note or something...

Comment: To elaborate on topo Reinstate Monica's comment, are the 0-length notes for unpitched percussion instruments such as snare drums?

Answer (score 5):

Many percussion instruments have a fixed-length sound and ignore note-off messages, but MIDI files must not omit note-off messages. So the timing of these messages does not matter.

Comment: Thanks! Can I please ask you to say a little more about what you mean when you say some percussion instruments ignore note off messages? I'm not sure I follow yet...

Comment: Presumably they are “one-shots” where the whole sample is played no matter how long the midi note, hence taking no notice of the note off.